# SQL Query to select a products brand and relating it to a third table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a task to get products info like top sales, date, and brands. However there is no field Brands in a product table. What I have is two separate tables for products and brands, in addition I have another product_sales table which is basically the main table for products sales but the main table doesn't know anything about brands.

I suppose I have to join somehow the two basic tables and then link them by product id to the main table.
For now, I believe I have to work with the two tables containing info about the brand.

**Brands** has {id, brandId, brandname, total }

**BrandsProducts** has {id, brandid, productId }

My query:

```
SELECT
    b.brandid, 
    b.brandname,
    p.productid
    FROM pgcdonbrands b, pgcdonbrandsproducts p
    WHERE b.brandid = p.brandid
```

This I believe returns the correct result, Brand name and Id, and which Product Id is related to that brand. My question is now, how do I go on about including this in my main query for Product Sales table. The end result should be Product Name and Brand Name.

Comment: Hi @iivo will same productId contain multiple times in productSales table?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. Since a sale would be added to productSales even on the same product.

Comment: so you use upper query as subquery by using INNER JOIN instead of comma and replace WHERE clause with ON.

Comment: I think I understand.. How would that look? Do you mind writing some pseudocode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this. As per your data you'll decide JOIN TYPE (LEFT/INNER).

```
SELECT *
FROM productSales ps
INNER JOIN (SELECT b.brandid, 
                 b.brandname,
                 p.productid
            FROM pgcdonbrands b
            INNER JOIN pgcdonbrandsproducts p
                    ON b.brandid = p.brandid) t
        ON ps.productid = t.productid;
```

Comment: Hi @iivo please check. you can use subquery with your main query as per requirement. Here I've used subquery because I don't know your table structure and your expectation.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  ...
FROM    BrandsProducts
INNER JOIN Brands ON BrandsProducts.brandid = BrandsProducts.brandid
WHERE   ...
```

By joining your tables like this, you can use them as one virtual table